# In Django, how to find rows which would violate a unique together constraint?

Tags: python, django, database, migration, unique-constraint

For the following API endpoint,

```
import json

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

from lucy_web.models import UserApn


@login_required
@require_POST
def save_apn(request, version):
    player_id = json.loads(request.body).get('player_id')
    if player_id:
        UserApn.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, player_id=player_id)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Here is the underlying model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from .timestamped_model import TimeStampedModel


class UserApn(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    player_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

The call to [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) has been  raising some `MultipleObjectsReturned` errors. To fix this, I'd like to impose a `unique_together` constraint on the `user` and `player_id`. Firstly, however, I have to write a data migration that eliminates rows that violate this unique together constraint.

How could I write a query that selects these? Right now the following has been proposed:

```
def remove_duplicate_apns(apps, schema_editor):
    UserApn = apps.get_model('lucy_web', 'UserApn')

    previous_user_id = None
    previous_player_id = None
    for apn in UserApn.objects.all().order_by('user_id', 'player_id'):
        if apn.user_id == previous_user_id and apn.player_id == previous_player_id:
            print(f'deleting {apn} (id: {apn.id})')
            apn.delete()
        else:
            previous_user_id = apn.user_id
            previous_player_id = apn.player_id
```

It seems, though, that this could also be done in a single query.

**Update**

I've found that one can pass the two fields, `user` and `player_id`, to `.values()`, and then check for duplicates using `.distinct()`. For example, the following test passes:

```
from django.test import TestCase

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.models import UserApn


class UserApnTest(TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user(username='jayz')
        apn1 = UserApn.objects.create(user=user, player_id='foo')
        apn2 = UserApn.objects.create(user=user, player_id='foo')
        apn3 = UserApn.objects.create(user=user, player_id='bar')

        self.assertEqual(
            len(UserApn.objects.values('user', 'player_id')) -
            len(UserApn.objects.values('user', 'player_id').distinct()), 1)
```

The problem remains, however, that the output from this is dictionaries with `user_id` and `player_id`, but the original `id` is lost, so I can't subsequently `get()` the duplicate objects and delete them. How can I do something similar but retain references to the duplicate objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to group the duplicate `UserApn`s into the following queryset:

```
UserApn.objects.all().difference(UserApn.objects.distinct('user', 'player_id'))
```

Note that passing multiple arguments to [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) only works on PostgreSQL.

Comment: "Only works on PostgreSQL" has been a really sastifying (and frequent) phrase since I started using it.